# Please ensure that `sails-cassandra` is a valid Sails/Waterline adapter

Tags: node.js, cassandra, sails.js

I have setup a sails project from production to local machine ( window). We are using **`sails-cassandra`**. Now when i am running **node app.js*. I am getting following error

```
> error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load! 
error: Error: There was an error
> attempting to load `sails-cassandra`. (Sails attempted to load this
> adapter because it is referenced by a datastore
> (`someCassandraServer`) in this app's configuration) Please ensure
> that `sails-cassandra` is a valid Sails/Waterline adapter, and that it
> is installed in this app.
```

Anybody have an idea what i am missing. My Cassandra database is setup on external server, i am able to ping that server.

Comment: And what about the config for this connector? When you moved from production, it may be pointing to localhost

Comment: No, i am pointing to production

Comment: Set log level to verbose and see if you get anything https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-log ?

Comment: Can you please share the output of `nodetool status` and `nodetool info`?

Comment: Two questions, 1. What version of Sails are you using? 2. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the adapter in your project, whilst in the project directory `npm uninstall sails-cassandra --save` once complete reinstall with `npm install sails-cassandra --save`. The error looks fairly generic, but clearly says that sails can't find sails-cassandra adapter.

Comment: i re-installed it again . it works